# How to convert a multiple variables column into many different boolean columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, pivot

I have this table:

```
ID     action
1       buy
1       sell
1       drop
```

I want turn it into this

```
 ID     buy     sell     drop
 1      Yes     Yes       Yes
```

That's all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    id,
    bool_or(action = 'buy')  has_buy,
    bool_or(action = 'sell') has_sell,
    bool_or(action = 'drop') has_drop
from mytable
group by id
```

This gives you boolean values (true or false) in the new columns rather than Yes/No strings, which is what you describe in your question.

If you want Yes/No, then:

```
select
    id,
    case when bool_or(action = 'buy')  then 'Yes' else 'No' end has_buy,
    case when bool_or(action = 'sell') then 'Yes' else 'No' end has_sell,
    case when bool_or(action = 'drop') then 'Yes' else 'No' end has_drop
from mytable
group by id
```